# Is sparkSession.stop() asynchronous?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I want to stop a spark session and exit, can I safely execute the following?

```
sparkSession.stop()
System.exit(1)
```

I am wondering if `sparkSession.stop()` is asynchronous or if System.exit(1) might interrupt `sparkSession.stop()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@stop():Unit) (I'm referring to version 2.2.1 here), `SparkSession.stop` just stops the underlying `SparkContext` (you can also check it [in the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L696-L703)).

The underlying operation is also synchronous, as you can see by having a look at the [code for the `SparkContext.stop` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1882-L2003).

Furthermore, consider that `SparkSession` implements the `Closeable` interface, which is generally meant to have a synchronous behavior (e.g. the interface is also implemented by [`AsynchronousFileChannel`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) which, despite being a natively asynchronous interface to files, adopts the synchronous behavior when it comes to [`stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html#close--)).

Comment: I'm new to scala, so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but what in the code you posted makes `SparkContext.stop` synchronous?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all (and welcome to the community). Unless there is something extremely well hidden (I haven't explored every single method, but I highly doubt we could find such a surprise), nothing in that method opens a new thread, which would make the method asynchronous. Furthermore, if more than one thread accesses the `stop` method, this code ensures that the bulk of the method in executed with a synchronized behavior: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1890-L1895

Comment: The only thing you may want to protect against is calling `spark.stop()` and `System.exit(1)` in two different, unsynchronized threads, but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, sparkSession.close() looks async.

```
while (!stopped) {
      // create spark session
      implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder
        .config(sparkConf)
        .getOrCreate()

      try {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE...
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          logger.error(e)
      } finally {
        spark.close()
        // Thread.sleep(10000)   without this sleep, you get error saying sparkSession already closed.
      }
}
```

if spark.close() is indeed sync, then you shouldn't get this error, because underlying sparkContext will be closed completely before one try to enter the next while loop.

Am I missing anything here?

**UPDATE:**
never mind, we found the root cause, some of the Datasets has reference to the previous sparkSession, so when previous sparkSession was closed, and if one tries to do `df.sparkSession.***`, this will give out sparkContext already closed issue, because this reference is to the closed context. Lesson learnt.